# loaded nib but the view outlet was not set while assigning a custom view for UITableView's header

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to make a custom view for `UITableView` header, but, unfortunately, I get an exception:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "ImagesView" nib but the view outlet was not set.'
```

First, in HomeViewController I created a tableView, then I created ImagesViewController with xib file, where designed my custom view.

And in the end I try to assign ImagesView as a header for my tableView:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    ImagesViewController *imagesView = [[ImagesViewController alloc] init];
    tableView.tableHeaderView = imagesView.view;

}
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm a newbie in iOS development and figure it out by myself.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You also call viewcontroller nib file.like this                         ImageViewcontroller *imageView=[[ImagesViewController alloc]initwithnibname:@"ImageViewController" bundle:nil];

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion works!

Comment: Welcome.if comment is helpful for you then click on arrow mark in my comment.

Comment: if my line of code work then I post my answer below please right mark this arrow so this will be helpful for other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this line of code

```
 {   
 ImageViewcontroller *imageView=[[ImagesViewController alloc]initwithnibname:@"ImageViewController" bundle:nil];       
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom header View with this method

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

which is part of [UITableView Delegate Protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

For example, one of my applications uses this method:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UIView *customHeaderView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    customHeaderView.frame = CGRectMake(40.0, 20.0, 300.0, 45.0);
    UILabel *headerText = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 0.0, 300, 32)];
    headerText.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    headerText.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE_FOOTER];
    headerText.numberOfLines = 0;
    headerText.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    if (section == 0) {
        headerText.text = @"";
    }
    if (section == 1) {
        headerText.text = SETTINGS_TEXT_PART0;
    }
    [customHeaderView addSubview:headerText];
    return customHeaderView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way,in the xib file of the tableviewcontroller itself, drag a uiview or imageview (do the design for the header here) into the working area but not into the mainview or tableview,then make an iboutlet called header ,then connect this iboutlet to the view,then in the tableviewcontrollers delegate method implementations

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return header;
}
```

add this

Answer (score 0):

In your `ImagesViewController` you haven't probably linked the `view` outlet with a view. You can do this in the Interface Builder by clicking the File's Owner and from Utilities click Connection Inspector there you can link the `view` outlet to your `UIView`.